# Intuition for hereditary torsion theories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, intuition, abelian-categories, torsion-theory

I'm looking for intuition and references for the definition of a hereditary torsion theory and two facts found [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsion+theory). First, the definition and facts:

> **Definition.** A torsion theory $(\mathcal T,\mathcal F$) is *hereditary* if $\mathcal T$ is closed under subobjects (aswell as quotient objects).
>
> **Theorem:** In an abelian category $\mathsf A$ satisfying [property sup](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/property+sup):
>
> - The assignment $A\mapsto t(A)$ which takes an object into its largest torsion subobject can, using the axiom of choice, be extended to a functor $t:\mathsf A \rightarrow \mathcal T$
> - A torsion theory is hereditary iff $t$ is left exact

- First of all I have no intuition at all for the notion of hereditary.
- Is the first part of the theorem mostly technical? What's a reference?
- What's the intuitive meaning of the left exactness of $t$? When does it have a right adjoint and what would it be? What about an analogous "torsion-free part" functor?

---

For future reference - does a question like this belong on MSE?

Comment: The inclusion $i \colon \mathcal T \hookrightarrow \mathsf A$ is a left adjoint of $t$. Did you mean to ask about a right adjoint?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen yes, sorry. Corrected.